# SQL Server Audit file

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have faced with some challenge regarding my audit. I need to save my audit events on a file, but file should be in a readable format ( like txt) which will allow to analyze it out of SSMS. XXXXX.sqlaudit format does not allow this. Maybe you know options that will help to export audit events` file to readable format ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Audit logs to either a binary file or Windows Application log or Windows Security log.  There are different options for reading the output depending on where you have logged to.  If you are logging to a binary file you could create a simple process that reads it with `sys.fn_get_audit_file` and outputs to a readable textfile, eg using SSIS, use an 'Execute SQL' task to run the following SQL and pipe the output to a text file:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file ( 'X:\SQLAudit\yourAuditName_*.sqlaudit', DEFAULT, DEFAULT );
```

You will need some way of tracking the files you have imported/exported so a simple table would help there.

A quick google shows someone else has done something similar with Powershell [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3444/automate-the-import-of-sql-server-audit-files-into-sql-server-using-powershell/).